# is there a way to combine (concat) one column's different values?

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a dictionary for 7 days. From 22th January to 29th. But there is two different data in one column in a day. Column name is `Last Update`. That values are I want to combine is `'1/25/2020 10:00 PM', '1/25/2020 12:00 PM'`. This values in the same column. So 25. January is Saturday. I want to combine them together as `Saturday`.

For understanding the column:

```
       Last Update
0      1/22/2020 12:00
1      1/22/2020 12:00
2      1/22/2020 12:00
3      1/22/2020 12:00
4      1/22/2020 12:00
            ...       
363    1/29/2020 21:00
364    1/29/2020 21:00
365    1/29/2020 21:00
366    1/29/2020 21:00
367    1/29/2020 21:00
```

i came so far:

```
day_map = {'1/22/2020 12:00': 'Wednesday', '1/23/20 12:00 PM': 'Thursday', 
           '1/24/2020 12:00 PM': 'Friday', .?.?.
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to convert date to datetime and use `pandas.dt` functions. In this case

```py
df["Last Update"] = df["Last Update"].astype("M8")

df["Last Update"].dt.weekday_name
# returns

0    Wednesday
1    Wednesday
2    Wednesday
3    Wednesday
4    Wednesday
Name: Last Update, dtype: object
```